# How to get Bulgarian Tourist Visa For an Indian Student in UK

Tags: visas, bulgaria

I am an Indian student in UK and after our exam I would like to visit Bulgaria with my other student friends.Now,problem is how to get Bulgarian visa from UK while I am in UK as an Indian student.

Comment: Are you currently resident in the UK?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to apply for it in Bulgarian embassy in the UK.

Here's the website of the London embassy: http://bulgarianembassy-london.org/ They have a section about visas.